# Wordpress General Header Links Not Working

Tags: html, wordpress, footer

I'm using wordpress for a website, and all I am trying to do is link to external sites in the general headers section.

To be very specific, I am creating this in the Settings / General Header section and typing my HTML in the footer box.

My actual html for the site is a bit more complex, but I added a very simple text link to demonstrate the issue. Here is the code:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"> Google </a>
```

Basically this link does nothing at all. Is there a restriction to using the general header section? Where else can I put this code to make it work? Any help is great, thanks!

Comment: What is this "General Headers" section?  Are you using a specific theme?  Try typing some non-html to verify that anything is appearing where you think it should.  Press CTRL + SHIFT + C in Chrome or (Firefox with Firebug) to inspect, and see if there is any HTML showing up.  Its possible that the theme is sanitizing your input, which removes HTML tags.

Comment: When you go to Wordpress admin panel, on the left side you have all of your different categories (such as pages, posts, appearance, etc.). When you click on the settings category, you get a new list of items. One of those items is titled "General Headers" and when you click on general headers, you are presented with to text boxes. One for the footer and one for the header. Basically all code I write in this section is showing up when inspecting the element; however the ability for a link to bring me to a new page just isnt working.

Comment: The theme I am using is Sky by Elegant Themes, but this setting is outside of the theme. I could very well be affecting the input, but everything like displaying images works fine, its just adding anything like mouse over or making the image a clickable link thank wont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that there was some random div that was over riding the above code, once removed, everything worked as expected!